# Difficulty implementing the Runnable interface with an Activity

Tags: android, multithreading

I have been trying to implement a `Runnable` in my application so I started with some easy procedure, but even this doesn't display anything on the `TextView`. Surprisingly, I have overridden the object's `run()`, but it still is not displaying.

```
package com.example.filer;
public class Filesearcher extends Activity implements Runnable {

TextView tvtis;
Thread tr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_filesearcher);
    tvtis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvfirst);
    tr = new Thread();
    tr.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        tvtis.setText("Started");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to touch views from any other thread than the main/UI thread. If you want to update a view while some work is being done, or after the work has finished, use an `AsyncTask`. I suggest you do [a little reading](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads).

Comment: You can't access Ui elements in Android outside of the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put your Runnable on a thread : `tr = new Thread(this);`

To switch to the UI thread from the other:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                tvtis.setText("started");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) of `runOnUiThread(Runnable)`

Comment: Yup the thread that has the view only can have access to it!! :) I got it and the thread is running fine I used a handler for this!!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
tr = new Thread();
```

to

```
tr = new Thread(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the UI from a Thread other than the UI Thread. Means - your Thread probably works fine, but the `tvis.setText()` does not (from within that thread). Try a simple `Log.d("tag", "does it work?")` instead to see if your Thread runs.

Comment: Your right it does not show anything even when now I have applied the solution shown by @Shridhar. Please help I am working on this since the past week now :(, but to no avail!!